# Search and replace in pairs in vim regex

Tags: vim, vi, spacemacs

I have a text file like this:

```
This is sentence 1: text I don't need
This is sentence 2? text I don't need
This is sentence 3? text I don't need
This is sentence 4: text I don't need
```

I know it's possible to do `%s/[:\|?].*/:` for example to replace everything that comes after `:` and `?` with `:`

Is it possible to replace everything that comes after `:` and `?` with `:` and `?` respectively?
I tried `%s/[:\|?].*/:\|?` and it doesn't work

Comment: Concerning `%s/[:\|?].*/:` you meant actually `%s/[:?].*/:` which is the correct one and what you are trying to do is  `%s/\(:\|?\).*/\1/` via **capture group**.

Comment: `%s/\(:\|?\).*/\1/` and `%s/\([:?]\).*/\1/` and `%s/[:?]\zs.*//` have all the same effect !

Comment: Ohhh I see, thanks!

Comment: I know I should ask a new question or edit this one but is it possible to use lookahead to achieve the same results in vim?  

For example: how would one express "delete everything _after_ `:` and `?`" in vim?

Comment: Use lookahead to assert what exactly ?

Comment: As far as I know, a lookahead is when you have a pattern and you want to process what's _after_ the pattern and not the actual characters that match the pattern. Am I wrong?

Comment: lookahead is an assertion which asserts that  what comes after the treatment position matches the pattern inside. See **[more](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)**.

Comment: Hmm I see, seems like I got it all wrong. Would it be possible and/or feasible to delete everything after `:` and `?` in vim though?

Comment: Try to understand lookaround and you will answer that question by yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will do that!

Answer (score 0):

```
:%s/\d\+.\zs.*//g
```

Using \zs vim will use everything after digits on substitution
see :h \zs